# Multiple Data Types for Single Variable in C

Tags: c, scheme

I am trying to implement basic cons, car and cdr of SCHEME in C. I have made a simple program that allows me to cons two integers as shown in the main program. However, I want my program to be able to cons a 'consed object' with a digit as well as cons a 'consed object' with another 'consed object' as shows below:

- (cons 2 3)
- (cons 2 (cons 2 3))
- (cons (cons 2 3) (cons 2 3))

Since the limitation arises because the data in the struct is of type int, is it possible to have a variable accept multiple data types in C? If yes, how? If not, is there another way to deal with this issue?
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct cons_object {
int data;
struct node* next;
} cons_object;

cons_object* cons(int x, int y )
{
cons_object* car = NULL;
cons_object* cdr = NULL;
car = malloc(sizeof(struct cons_object));
cdr = malloc(sizeof(struct cons_object));
car->data = x;
car->next = cdr;
cdr->data = y;
cdr->next = NULL;
return car; /*returns the pointer car*/
}

int car(cons_object* list) /*takes in a consed object*/
{
cons_object* car = list;
int y;
y = car->data;
return y;
}

int cdr(cons_object* list)
{
cons_object* cdr = list;
cdr = cdr->next;
int z;
z= cdr->data;
return z;

}

int main ()
{
int y = car (cons(33,42));
printf("%d\n",y);
int z = cdr (cons(3,4));
printf("%d\n",z);
return 0;

}
```

Comment: look up [union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_type)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Further to ratchet freak's comment, look up *discriminated* union, or [tagged union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union).

You can make your data type a `void *`, but you *also* need to track what it really points to. That is, at some point you need to figure out if it's an integer or a double or another list.

The tagged union itself might look something like this:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

enum TypeTag { NoType, CharType, IntType, DoubleType, ConsType };
union Value {
    char c;
    int i;
    double d;
    void *p;
};
struct TaggedType {
    enum TypeTag type;
    union Value value;
};
```

and the cons code can use it - without worrying about what type is really inside the `TaggedType` structure - like this:

```c
struct ConsNode {
    struct TaggedType value;
    struct ConsNode *next;
};

struct ConsNode *cons(struct TaggedType value, struct ConsNode *next) {
    struct ConsNode *head = malloc(sizeof *head);
    head->value = value;
    head->next = next;
    return head;
}
struct TaggedType *car(struct ConsNode *head) {
    return &head->value;
}
struct ConsNode *cdr(struct ConsNode *head) {
    return head->next;
}
```

Then all you need is the boxing/unboxing code to work with actual concrete types:

```c
struct TaggedType mkint(int i) {
    struct TaggedType value = { IntType, {.i=i} };
    return value;
}
struct TaggedType mkdbl(double d) {
    struct TaggedType value = { DoubleType, {.d=d} };
    return value;
}

int toint(struct TaggedType *data) {
    assert(data->type == IntType);
    return data->value.i;
}
double todbl(struct TaggedType *data) {
    assert(data->type == DoubleType);
    return data->value.d;
}

int main () {
    struct ConsNode *list = cons(mkint(33), cons(mkint(42), NULL));
    int y = toint(car(list));
    assert(y == 33);
    assert(toint(car(cdr(list))) == 42);
    return y;
}
```

Note that most list operations don't know or care about the type stored in each node - this only becomes important where you *do* something with it.

Answer (score 2):

Make it a `void *`.  Then it can point to anything.  Memory management is up to you.

This will result in not having any type checking.  If you go down this path, see http://libcello.org/ for what is possible.  (But if you want to go down this path, why are you writing in C?)

Comment: void* to accommodate generic types is a very normal use of C - I disagree with "why are you writing in C".

Comment: @JustinMeiners I think he just means, if you're trying to write in a LISP style, why don't you use a LISP, which is a totally reasonable question...

Comment: But if you're trying to _write_ LISP, starting with LISP isn't necessarily a helpful suggestion

Comment: @Useless I disagree.  There is a long history of implementing Lisps in Lisp.  For example SCIP is mostly about how to write Scheme in Scheme.  This history goes back to the beginning - the very first implementation of Lisp was written in Lisp!  (And then unexpectedly hand compiled to assembly.  Quite a surprise to the team which hadn't finished designing the language.)

Comment: @JustinMeiners did you follow the link?  If you're going to wind up with dynamic functional code in C with no type checking, the "in C" bit doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me.

Comment: @btilly I don't think "going down that path" referred to writing a higher level language (like libcello stuff) It just referred to handling generic types (the way I interpreted it)

Comment: @btilly - that's fair, I think what I meant to say was _if OP asked about implementing LISP in C, suggesting OP implements it in LISP instead isn't necessarily helpful_.

Comment: I have worked on implementing LISP in LISP (SICP). I am attempting to build a basic LISP interpreter in C.